# kubectl patch using yaml - no error, but no change

Tags: kubectl

I like the readability of yaml, therefore I am trying this(no json) - do you know why this runs without error, but do not update/change anything?

```
kubectl patch configmap/config-domain -n knative-serving --type merge -p '
data:
  example.com:""
'
```

And this is working, but I have no idea why:

```
kubectl patch configmap/config-network -n knative-serving --type merge -p '
data:
  autoTLS: Enabled
  httpProtocol: Redirected
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample `cm` with two keys `key1` and `key2`,  the output format is `yaml`:

```
k get cm my-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  key1: config1
  key2: config2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-22T14:15:07Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:key1: {}
        f:key2: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-22T14:15:07Z"
  name: my-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "755842"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/my-config
  uid: 18d87151-ae27-4aa1-8cf1-eee609c0dd7f
```

Patching the `cm`:

```
 k patch cm my-config  -p $'data:\n key1: "new_config1"'
configmap/my-config patched
```

Here is the updated `cm`:

```
k get cm my-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  key1: new_config1 #<----------this is updated
  key2: config2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-22T14:15:07Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:key2: {}
    manager: kubectl-create
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-22T14:15:07Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        f:key1: {}
    manager: kubectl-patch
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-22T14:16:11Z"
  name: my-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "755928"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/my-config
  uid: 18d87151-ae27-4aa1-8cf1-eee609c0dd7f
```

Similarly, you can o/p the `cm` in `json`, you can built the query after printing the `cm` in `json` format.

Comment: Thanks, I should have stated more clear that I want to use yaml - updated the question and marked this as useful.